# Eclipse vs manual compiling differences

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have this piece of code:

```
String packageName = "";
    try {
        packageName = Class.forName(new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()).getPackageName();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I use it as a part of my Eclipse project, everything goes fine, but when I compile that same .java file from Command Promt, I get the following error:

```
symbol:   method getPackageName()
location: class Class<CAP#1>
 where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
 CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

Is there any way to improve this piece of code so that it works?

Comment: Help us by providing the command line, but also the java version you're using with `javac --version`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error tells you that you're using a method, `Class.getPackageName()`, that doesn't exist. Looking at [its javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getPackageName()) shows that this method exists, but since Java 9.

Conclusion: you use Java 9 or later in Eclipse, but Java 8 or sooner in your command prompt.

Decide what **actual** version of Java you want to use, and use that same version everywhere. Then read the javadoc of that version of the JDK to know which methods are available.

Comment: Agree should be java version mismatch